# Query isnt running from PHP engine

Tags: php

I have created these 3 files of code to download a CSV and import it into a MySQL DB. The end result query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/POS/tmp/test.csv' INTO TABLE `wavepricelist` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '' IGNORE 1 LINES (`productID`,`brand`,`productName`,`priceSingle`,`inStock`,`EAN`,`vendorID`,`category`,`imageURL`,`weight`)
```

I have a seperate PHP server and MySQL server. If I run this query from my MySQL console, it runs without problems. I have also made sure that test.csv is on the local C-drive of the mysql to with all rights needed to read it.

I just can't figure out why this query doesn't execute. The file returns no error (turned them all on). Just no data in table.

http://ideone.com/m3saqt

Comment: My database class: http://ideone.com/243Lsl

Comment: Execution file: http://ideone.com/243Lsl

Answer (score 1):

I'm really sorry guys for taking your time! I just fixed it.

After reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html again, it just popped in my head that the user that tries to run the script probably doesnt have the "file" global privileges.

I changed that, and now it runs perfectly.

Thanks again for the tips and support.

Answer (score 0):

The servers are set up in a different way. Play with the LOAD options is my advice.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
Try with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried that and it did not make a difference I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Put a MySQL client on the PHP server and make sure you are able to authenticate to your database.

If not

```
select * from db
```

and make sure your PHP server has permission to connect to your MySQL database. If not or if you haven't already run...

```
update db set Host='202.54.10.20' where Db='yourdb';
```

Replacing the ip address with your PHP servers IP address and the db with your database name.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try that already. A basic query runs perfectly fine from the php script and gives results. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to put a MySQL server on the web server to see if that helps.